# Is "Talk no Jutsu" actually a thing?

Tags: naruto

(Preface: I have not read or watched Naruto.)

In the context of a discussion of some other anime, there was a reference to a thing called the "Talk no Jutsu" in Naruto. Upon looking this thing up, I came across [this wikia page](http://konohalibrary.wikia.com/wiki/Talk_No_Jutsu), which describes the nature of this technique. This looks like a joke on its face (I mean, we make jokes about Touma doing this sort of thing in Index all the time), but the page was written with nothing to suggest that it was a joke, so I'm a bit confused. I checked out a couple other discussions on the internet and am still having difficulty figuring out whether or not they're joking.

So - is "Talk no Jutsu" actually a technique of Naruto's?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a joke, a glance at the home page of the Konoha Libraries site you provided says:

> Remember, there's plenty of serious information banks on Naruto already. We will never be as big as any one of them so just have fun with your articles. Go nuts. Reference people from the forum or threads you love. Just remember to keep it in good spirits.

Talk no Jutsu refers to the ability of Naruto (and many main characters from many anime series) to talk the antagonists out of their evil ways, and "show them the light".

Comment: Aha. It really does behoove me to do a little more research, I suppose. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The "LOOL!" at the end of the article seems to pretty clearly show that it's a joke, as well.

Comment: @BrianS Well, I don't know about that. Anime wikias are not exactly paragons of good encyclopedic style.

Comment: although it is a joke , no one can proof except for kishi that it isn't valid. and the way kishi is taking naruto now i think its just a matter of time that You get obliterated with the ultimate combined talk no jutsu of shinobi world.  :P

Comment: It is derived from teh fact that in the naruto universe, there are very few True villains in the series. Even Madara, Tobi, Pein, down to Zabuza are not Evil, they are misguided, trying to achieve a goal by any means, and may have supressed their true feelings on the subject. Madara wanted peace and founded the Leaf village on that fact. Then he found a way he truly believed was far better, The Infinite Tsukuyomi, and was willing to kill half the world for perfect happiness for the other half.

Answer (score -1):

"Talk no Jutsu" is one *of* Naruto's abilities. It is not an actual Jutsu. It is basically a joke on how Naruto can talk people out of their evil ways and make them join his side.

Comment: You're not really adding anything new to this question.